# Как запустить на Google cloud function Python-скрипт, который парсит с помощью Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-cloud

Есть Python-скрипт, который парсит с помощью Selenium.
Тестовая функция в Google cloud function выглядит так:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def launch_search(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    return 'Success'
```

Ошибка, которую выдает GCF, такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обычно для создания инстанса нужен путь к exe-файлу, вроде того **driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')**.

Как скрипт запустить в Google cloud function? Где взять путь к exe-файлу в этом случае?

Comment: Нужно скачать `chromedriver`, распаковать и положить куда-нибудь в `/usr/bin/`, по крайней мере в `Google Colab` я так делал и всё получилось. Ну либо поищите через `find`, может найдёте уже готовый, в колабе я установленного не нашёл.